# Firestore - orderBy best match in array-contains-any query

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I have a collection of documents in Firestore which has a field which is an array of strings, these are tags that have been added to the data.

The user can filter the data by selecting and deselecting these tags on the frontend so I'm doing an array-contains-any to query Firestore.

I then score the results on best match, so documents that match more tags are sorted to the top and displayed to the top of the page for the user.

I'm now trying to paginate this data, using a startAfter with a document snapshot as the cursor and a limit. But I need to ensure that higher scoring documents are not excluded when the limit does not extend to that document in the default ordering (ascending by id). I am not ordering the results set in any specific way as it is.

My question is, is there any way to query Firestore in such a way that it can order the results of the query by the most tags that match in the array-contains-any query, or if not, how can i change my data model/logic to do this in a way that will scale.

Querying the entire dataset and implementing the pagination myself does not seem like the most practical solution.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, is there any way to query Firestore in such a way that it can order the results of the query by the most tags that match in the array-contains-any query

No, Firestore can't order query results based on the size of a list field.

> how can i change my data model/logic to do this in a way that will scale.

You can store the size of the list in another field, and use that field for ordering.  You will have to make sure to keep that field up to date if the list changes.

Comment: The size of the array is not what is used to calculate the score that i sort the results by, it's how many items in that array match against the query array-contains-any. So the tags in a document might have 10 items in it. 2 of those might match 2 items in array-contains-any the query. this would give it a score of 2 for that query and I would then sort the results based on this number, higher scoring elements featuring higher up in the returned array.

Comment: Still not possible, and even harder to workaround on your own.  You would need to precompute all possible combinations of all list values and store the sums of each combination separately.